# Power BI Desktop add the value of two rows by Staff Name

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I want to add the value for two rows for a specific StaffName and Allowance. the Allowance types are "R-02 - Research Component for HDR supervision" and "R-03 - Research". So for the following example:

[image]

Acuna = 70, Agosti = 290 and Akagi = 22

I will then compare this value to ensure it is less than 40% of their FTE.

Answer (score 0):

I have found:

```
Measure = calculate(sum('sdowner SPV_REP_PERSONALTAB'[Total]),FILTER(ALL('sdowner SP_ALLOWANCETYPE'),'sdowner SP_ALLOWANCETYPE'[Allowance]="R-02 - Research Component for HDR supervision")) + calculate(sum('sdowner SPV_REP_PERSONALTAB'[Total]),FILTER(ALL('sdowner SP_ALLOWANCETYPE'),'sdowner SP_ALLOWANCETYPE'[Allowance]="R-03 - Research"))
```

This gives me:

[image]

So now I need to figure out how to only display the Measure for the last row of each name. I tried this:

```
Measure 2 = if(containsstring(min('sdowner SP_ALLOWANCETYPE'[Allowance]), "R-03 - Research"),calculate(sum('sdowner SPV_REP_PERSONALTAB'[Total]),FILTER(ALL('sdowner SP_ALLOWANCETYPE'),'sdowner SP_ALLOWANCETYPE'[Allowance]="R-02 - Research Component for HDR supervision")) + calculate(sum('sdowner SPV_REP_PERSONALTAB'[Total]),FILTER(ALL('sdowner SP_ALLOWANCETYPE'),'sdowner SP_ALLOWANCETYPE'[Allowance]="R-03 - Research")), "")
```

However that gave me:

[image]

So I applied a filter to Total greater than zero. To give me:

[image]